# Jquery. mouseenter and mouseleave with delay. How to stop animate events?

Tags: jquery, delay, reusability, mouseenter, mouseleave

Recently began working with jquery as with javascript.

By moving the cursor twice (during pause) DIVS leave again and again.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tworog/X2y6k/1/

How do I limit?

Forgive me for my English. TNX!:))

Comment: what are you trying to limit? Only animate one time?

Comment: yes! so that when you hover over again (during pause) the animation is not repeated

Answer (score 0):

maybe you searching for `clearQuery()` so if you mouseenter twice you clear the animation and start it again.